# Custom Taxonomy Not Being Recognized by is_tax()

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I created a `taxonomy.php` template that works fine for the default stuff, but I realized my theme has default'd to `index.php` when trying to load a custom taxonomy I created (IE: open `website.com/age/something` in my browser). According to the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), it should work? Here is how it's created:

```
function custom_events_taxonomy() {

$labels = array('name' => _x( 'Ages', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'singular_name' => _x( 'Age', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
  'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Age' ),
  'all_items' => __( 'All Ages' ),
  'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Age' ),
  'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Age:' ),
  'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Age' ),
  'update_item' => __( 'Update Age' ),
  'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Age' ),
  'new_item_name' => __( 'New Age Name' ),
  'menu_name' => __( 'Ages' ),
 );

// Now register the taxonomy
  register_taxonomy( 'age', array( 'post' ), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'age' ),
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_events_taxonomy', 0 );
```

During troubleshooting, I was looking into `template-loader.php` and saw that when it runs the `is_tax()` method, it returns false. Not sure what I missed or if I am approaching this incorrectly.

What I'd like to happen is Wordpress to use my `taxonomy.php` for these custom taxonomies I register, but I cannot figure out why `is_tax()` returns false.

Comment: What do you mean by "when trying to load a custom taxonomy I created"? Are you going to `website.com/age/something`? How do you know it's using index.php and not taxonomy.php?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I go to a url similar to what you suggest, and it loads a list of posts instead of the thumbnail rows I made. I did a `var_dump` in both `taxonomy.php` and `index.php` and the output came from `index.php`. When I used a debugger, I stepped through the code, and saw `is_tax()` is returning false.

Comment: Have you cleared your permalinks yet after creating your taxonomy?

Comment: I went and changed the permalinks, saved, and then changed them back and saved again if that clears them.

Comment: FYI, usually all you have to do to clear your permalinks is visit the permalinks page.  It has a function built into it called [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) that cleans/creates new permalink structures.